# How to Controller Layer Test feat simple code example

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, tdd

code : https://github.com/mijosan/test-practice/tree/master/mybatis

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class UserController {

  private final UserService userService;

  @PostMapping(value="/v1/user")
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> postUser(@RequestBody UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto) {
      Long userId = userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto);

      return CommonUtil.getResponseEntity(UserResponseDto.builder()
                                                              .userId(userId)
                                                              .build()
                                                              , HttpStatus.OK
                                                              , "회원 등록 완료");
  }

}
```

Here is my test code

```
@WebMvcTest
public class UserControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @MockBean
  UserService userService;

  UserSaveRequestDto userSaveRequestDto;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
      userSaveRequestDto = UserSaveRequestDto.builder()
          .userName("test")
          .userPhoneNumber("01026137832")
          .build();
  } 

  @DisplayName("MockMvc를 이용한 postUser slice 테스트")
  @Test
  public void postUserTest() throws Exception {
      // given
      given(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).willReturn(1L);
      String content = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userSaveRequestDto);

      // when
      MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/user")
                      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .content(content))
                          .andExpect(status().isOk())
                          .andReturn();
    
      // then
      String result = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

      System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

and I received an exception of "java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>"

However, it works well if you test it with a swagger.

Where is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify you test code to

```
...
.content(content))
    .andDo(result -> {
        result.getResolvedException().printStackTrace();
    })
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
...
```

you will find in a log

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.example.mybatis.dto.ResponseDto
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
....
```

The cause of the 500 is that controller is not able to serialize your `ResponseDto`. You need to add `lombok.Getter` on your `ResponseDto`.

Comment: But I have an additional question. ResponseDto is created using the Builder pattern, when is the Get method used?

Comment: The default configuration of ObjectMapper in Spring is: For object serialization (object to String) use getters, and for object deserialization (String to object) use setters. In your case you were missing getters.

Comment: At what line does serialization currently occur in that code?

Comment: You can see it when you take a look at the full exception I mentioned in the answer. In short: when some of your controller functions return some value and the function has annotation @ResponseBody, then Spring will take the return value and serialize it to the JSON (when it is object and not a primitive) and return it to your REST client. In your case the ResponseBody is taken from the RestController annotation and applied on all functions of the controller class.

Comment: oh my god... i forgoted it.. Can I ask you one more question? "given(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).willReturn (1L);" returns 0 without returning 1L. Why?,,, this is last question

Comment: I am not sure about the `given` approach... I am familiar with the `when` keyword - see https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-behavior. In your case it would be something like `Mockito.\`when\`(userService.insertUser(userSaveRequestDto)).thenReturn(1L)`. You need to escape the `when` function name because `when` is a keyword in kotlin.